# delete button for deleting information is not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Currently I am trying to delete the data from ms access with my solution but it is currently not working. I have listed message box on button delete but it is not showing up and it doesnt show any error when I start it. Here's the code:

```
 MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Delete?", "Deletion",_
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If DialogResult.Yes Then
        Function1()

        UserHomepage.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf DialogResult.No Then
        Me.Show()
        UserHomepage.Hide()
        lblname.Hide()
        txtsid.ResetText()
    End If


    cmdDelete.CommandText = "Delete from student where student_id = " + txtsid.Text + ";"
    cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdDelete.Connection = cnnOLEDB
    cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

this is for function 1^

Comment: How are you calling this function? Did you set  OnClick event for your button?

Comment: can you explain what you mean @MihaiAdrian?

Comment: my function 1 is : 
cmdDelete.CommandText = "Delete from student where student_id = " + txtsid.Text + ";"
    cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdDelete.Connection = cnnOLEDB
    cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: I mean... You say the msgBox does not appear, neither does an error. Are you sure your code runs?

Comment: What's the data type of the student_id column?

Comment: @JohnMo its number datatype

Answer (score 0):

1. We needed to know what event the code was in to understand why it is not being called. I put it in a button that calls the code when clicked.
2. If you want a result from your message box set up a variable to hold the result. Then test the result against a DialogResult enumeration value. In your case, you only have Yes or No so you don't need to test for the second condition (DialogResult.No) just use an else.
3. I have no idea what Function1 is or why you are calling it. Name your variables, functions and subs so they mean something.
4. You get a connection from some mysterious place. I don't know if it is an open connection (I hope not!).
5. Using...EndUsing statements ensure that your objects are closed and disposed properly even if there is an error. Closing connections is very important.
6. You can set the .Text property and the .Connection properties of the Command object in the constructor of the Command.
7. When you concatenate strings use the & not the +. This avoids code confusion when this could be addition.
8. However, never use concatenation in SQL strings. You could have malicious input from a user. Always use parameters. Access does not care what you call your parameter. Access only cares about the order in which they are added. Doesn't matter here since we have only one parameter.
9. To execute your command needs an open connection.
10. Close your connection as soon as possible.

`

```
 Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
            Dim dr As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Delete?", "Deletion",
                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            If dr = DialogResult.Yes Then
                Using cnnOLEDB As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
                    Using cmdDelete As New OleDbCommand("Delete from student where student_id = @ID;", cnnOLEDB)
                        cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        cmdDelete.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtsid.Text
                        cnnOLEDB.Open()
                        cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        cnnOLEDB.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
                UserHomepage.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                Me.Show()
                UserHomepage.Hide()
                lblname.Hide()
                txtsid.ResetText()
            End If
        End Sub`
```

Comment: What is the workaround for the number list and code formatting bug?

Comment: Found out if you add <!-- language: lang-vb.net --> before the code block you can then format as normal with the buttons.